# Hive Syntax Process Control

Tags: hadoop, syntax, process, hive

I have several hive scripts files (+350 .hql) which are related among them in a sense that one script creates a table that another script need. The problem is that always appear a lot of bugs related with a consume a table or column that no script creates. So the question: is there any way to launch just a syntax validator of hive,  or take the scripts and just create metadata instead all the tables (which take a long time) just for test the relation of the scripts works fine?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about a solution, but Im not sure if is the optimum solution. Given the principal input is  from sqoop tables, the first idea could be replace the reference those tables by references to dummy sqoop tables or input tables which just have a few rows or no rows, in order to just create metadata. After this all subsequent scripts just will use empty tables as input (or table with few rows) instead to process complete heavies tables